# constraint that calls for the previous/next set member in indexed Set

Tags: python, pyomo

Does this example somehow also work with (string-)indexed Sets? 
In my case I get the following Error:

'IndexedSet' object has no attribute 'next'

Working example with non indexed Sets:

> ```
> m.s = Set(initialize=['A','B','C'], ordered=True)
> m.v = Var(m.s)
>
> def _c_rule(m, i):
>     if i == 'A':
>         return Constraint.Skip
>     return m.v[i] <= m.v[m.s.prev(i)]
> m.c = Constraint(m.s, rule=_c_rule)
>
> # Or the opposite way
> def _c2_rule(m, i):
>     if i == 'C':
>         return Constraint.Skip
>     return m.v[m.s.next(i)] <= m.v[i]
> m.c2 = Constraint(m.s, rule=_c2_rule)
> ```
>
> src: [Constraint that calls for the previous set member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43047684/constraint-that-calls-for-the-previous-set-member)

Not working:

```
model = ConcreteModel()


model.S = Set(("A", "B", "C"),initialize=("A", "B", "C"), ordered=True)

print(model.S.next(model.S["A"]))
```

If not, is there a work-around?

Comment: Could you show the code that doesn't work instead of the code that does?

Comment: Edited! and added

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reconsidering your use of an indexed `Set`. While they are allowed in Pyomo, there is almost always a better way to accomplish your goal using non indexed `Set` components or native Python lists.

That being said, here is a work around for your question. The problem is that you're 1) running afoul of some of the behind-the-scenes processing that is done when you declare a Pyomo component and 2) you're misunderstanding what the `next` function can be called on.

To start with the first problem, Pyomo components are expected to be indexed by Pyomo `Set` components. While we allow you to declare indexing sets for Pyomo components using native Python sets, lists, and tuples, under-the-hood Pyomo is generating a `Set` component for you if you didn't pass one in. This means that when you write the following:

```
m.s = Set(('A','B','C'), initialize=['D','E','F'])
```

you actually end up with two `Set` components on the model, the one you declared and the one that Pyomo implicitly created to store `['A','B','C']`. You can see this if you `pprint` the model:

```
>>> m.pprint()
2 Set Declarations
s : Dim=1, Dimen=1, Size=9, Domain=None, ArraySize=3, Ordered=Insertion, Bounds=None
    Key : Members
      A : ['D', 'E', 'F']
      B : ['D', 'E', 'F']
      C : ['D', 'E', 'F']
s_index : Dim=0, Dimen=1, Size=3, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Bounds=None
    ['A', 'B', 'C']

2 Declarations: s_index s
```

The problem is that this implicitly created Set, `s_index`, is not ordered which means the `next` and `prev` methods will not work with it. So to get around this, you have to explicitly declare this `Set` component:

```
m.a = Set(initialize=['A','B','C'], ordered=True)
m.s = Set(m.a, initialize=['D','E','F'], ordered=True)
```

The second part of the problem is that the `next` and `prev` methods can only be called on **elements** of a `Set` component and not on **indices**. This means that the following lines will work:

```
print(m.s['A'].next('D'))
print(m.s[m.a.next('A')])
```

but this will not:

```
print(m.s.next('D'))
```